# Counting Votes in Python Using Dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that takes filename as the input and returns a dictionary having keys equal to candidate's names and values equal to the number of votes they received.

This is what the text file looks like:

```
1-5-102 STEPHEN_WILLIAMS IP 48
1-5-102 KURT_BILLS R 303
1-5-102 AMY_KLOBUCHAR DFL 575
1-10-102 STEPHEN_WILLIAMS IP 6
1-10-102 KURT_BILLS R 205
1-10-102 AMY_KLOBUCHAR DFL 273
```

In each line: precinct number, name, party, and number of votes.

I want the output to be a dictionary with the key being the candidate name and the value being the total number of votes thee candidate has. Any ideas how to start this?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] in order to further assist you?

Comment: Downvoted because this is not the place where you can ask us to do you homework

Answer (score 3):

You can use default dict to sum up integers like so

```
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(int)
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        precinct, name, party, votes = line.split()
        counts[name] += int(votes)
```